# Variable Use in Where Clause, In Script

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am uncertain about this use of a field within a row variable, which has been loaded in a ‘for’ loop.

```
declare
    r_pers_rec   &appOwner..personsTbl%ROWTYPE;

    cursor getItems is
            SELECT Fld1, Fld2
            FROM srcTbl;
begin
    for Rec in getItems 
    loop
        BEGIN
            SELECT * INTO r_pers_rec
            FROM   &appOwner..personsTbl
            WHERE  personnel_id = Rec.Fld1;
        END;
    end loop;
end;
```

Can `Rec.Fld1` be used that way?

Comment: Yes, that looks fine. (You don't need the inner begin/end, but those aren't a problem.) What exactly are you uncertain about? Have you tried it and had a problem? If so, what happened and what error did you get? Or is it a hypothetical question (which would have been quicker to test yourself)?

Comment: the following is interpreted literally: 'SELECT * INTO r_pers_rec FROM   &appOwner..personsTbl WHERE  personnel_id = ' but the 'Rec.Fld1' is a variable, so to speak. The begin and end is because in the real script there is an Exception clause for that section. I stripped that out in putting the code here on S.O.

Comment: After this runs, I try to verify that using dbms_output.put_line(r_pers_rec.first_name'); (etc.).  I get 'expression is of wrong type, though.

Comment: Yes, it's treated as a bind variable, effectively. Your last comment isn't about that though, which is rather confusing. Your question should show the code that actually errors, and the full error message/stack.

Comment: I head out in 13 minutes. It is really hard to know just where the error happens, because TOAD's edit window and Oracle's response do not give useful line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is "Yes, you can use `rec.Fld1` in the `WHERE` clause, as shown".

The long answer is "Yes, but in total your script will only function properly if run from SQL*Plus or some other client which interprets substitution variables (here, `&appOwner`) in the same manner as does SQL*Plus. You should also probably have an exception handler for `NO_DATA_FOUND`, as the second SELECT could throw that exception if there's no value on PERSONSTBL for a given value of SRCTBL.FLD1".

Perhaps the best answer is "Just get rid of the problem". Rewrite the script to eliminate the second `SELECT` by building it into the cursor, as follows:

```
BEGIN
  FOR aRec IN (SELECT s.FLD1, s.FLD2, p.*
                 FROM srcTbl s
                 INNER JOIN &appOwner..personsTbl p
                   ON p.PERSONNEL_ID = s.FLD1)
  LOOP
    NULL;  -- Do whatever you need to do with your data here.
  END LOOP;
END;
```

As someone smarter than me once observed, "I know I'm doing writing code not when there is nothing left to add, but when there is nothing left to take away".

The above will do the same as your original code, except that the second select can't throw a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception - instead, there will simply be no row returned if a value of SRCTBL.FLD1 is not found on the PERSONSTBL table.

If you really want to have the data from SRCTBL to *always* be returned, whether or not matching data is found on PERSONSTBL, change the script to

```
BEGIN
  FOR aRec IN (SELECT s.FLD1, s.FLD2, p.*
                 FROM srcTbl s
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN &appOwner..personsTbl p
                   ON p.PERSONNEL_ID = s.FLD1)
  LOOP
    NULL;  -- Do whatever you need to do with your data here. Note that in
           -- this case the PERSONSTBL values in aRec will not be populated
           -- (all will be NULL) if there is no matching row on PERSONSTBL
           -- for a given value of SRCTBL.FLD1
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: If I click on the "Answer Your Question" button, is that going to close this thread to other people submitting answers?

Comment: The rows in scrTbl contain the file names of .PDFs in a folder, awaiting processing.  For each file name, I need to add a record to a table (not any of the tables thus far mentioned in this question), using (among other things) values found in the persons table. Ultimately, the contents of the .PDF are going to be processed and stored. The file name stored in the srcTbl identifies a file to be processed, as well as a record in the persons table (the first 10 characters of the filename do, that is).

Comment: At this point in the development, I am just trying to verify the process up to the point of getting the record out of the persons table. Once that succeeds, I will incorporate the next steps in the script, and run THAT looking for bugs and syntax errors.  Once I get the whole script functioning, I will turn it loose on the real data and .PDF files.